# I have 4 motors connected to their own ESC (that is connected to a power distribution board), how do I connect this to Arduino uno? (Drone)

Tags: motor, drone

I am currently working with a bigger drone that I want to connect with an arduino uno.

The motor and ESC that are already soldered together and connected are these: https://hobbyking.com/en_us/mt1806-brushless-combo-include-esc-5030cw-ccw.html

I have also connected it to a power distribution board where I succesfully can connect my 3s lipo battery.

What is currently missing is where I should put the 3 pins on each ESC onto the arduino board. So there are 12 pins in total.

The color on the 3 wires on each ESC are: yellow, red and brown.

Yellow is the signal if i am not mistaken and those should be connected on the PWM pins where I control each motor in the code.

When it comes to the red it is + power and should I ignore to connect these pins? I would like for my battery to power both the motors and the arduino so of course I would prefer to connect it to the arduino uno if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are just some clarifications for you:

- Signal pins don't ***have*** to be connected to PWM pins. ***AFAIK***, any digital pins should work.
- **All** grounds togheter! Glad you got that right!
- Connect VCC of ESCs directly to the power supply.
- Connect power supply to VIn of Arduino (not 5V because you are going to grill it!)

---

**Uptdate**

- Yes, you can probably solder all the VCC wire of the ESCs togheter.
- By power supply, I meant connecting it directly to the battery.

---

- To power the Uno, connect the battery+ to the VIn pin of the UNO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! So far so good :)
1. Ok!
2. Ok!
3/4. Do i do the following: Solder all of the VCC of the ESC (the red wire) the same way like I do with the ground and then I connect it to a power supply module? Is this a power supply module I can use? https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Smart-Electronics-MB102-MB-102-Solderless-Breadboard-Power-Supply-Module-3-3V-5V-for-Arduino-Board/32569124727.html?spm=2114.40010208.4.1.Pm4T84 It is for a breadboard i think but can it work with an arduino uno? When it comes to powering teh arduino I am a bit unsure how to do it.

Comment: This is one of my first projects so therefor I am very rookie in some areas!

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hi! I was just wondering. I have a 4s battery now that I plan to hookup to a arduino pro mini 5v board instead of a Uno-board. So instead of putting the battery wire to the Vln of the arduino uno I will put it on the "RAW" on the arduino pro mini. Will a 4s or 3s lipo make any difference?

Comment: Pro Mini's regulators are quiet bad. I'll suggest to put it to a down converter before passing it to the Arduino.

Comment: this is where i will attach the battery: https://hobbyking.com/en_us/hobby-king-quadcopter-power-distribution-board.html to my power distribution board and from that board i will connect the voltage to the RAW and the other pin to the gnd. Does the PDB work as a converter?